# VueJS model properties not binding if they are not in original list of properties

Tags: vue.js, data-binding

In `VueJs`, if an object I have in my `data` has a property with a default value, it will bind correctly as I manipulate it. However, if I later set a brand new property, that new property value will not bind.

The best way I can explain this is by the following example: https://jsbin.com/kahaxocohu/edit?html,js,output

If I enter in values for the `make` (Honda, Toyota, etc), the DOM updates propertly. However, if I enter in a value for `year`, the value is not rendered just above it inside the `div`.

If I were to instead change the default object to be the following, both properties `make` and `year` would bind correctly: `car: { make: 'Honda', year: '2012' }`.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is not a bug. It is, however, a common pitfall for users who are new to Vue – especially those with an Angular background.

When Vue initializes, it [adds reactive getters and setters](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html) to each property in the Vue instance's `data` object. However, Vue cannot setup reactive getters and setters for properties that don't exist.

If you want a property to be reactive, it must be initialized with a default value:

```
var app = new Vue({
    el: '#app',
    data: {
        car: {
            make: '',
            year: ''
        }
    }
});
```

Comment: Kudos to Angular for handling this for me. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

To make your first example reactive, data property needs to have getter and setter. You can read about it [here](https://v2.vuejs.org/v2/guide/reactivity.html).

In short example if your data looks like that:

```
data() {
  return {
    car: {
      make: '',
    },
  },
},
```

and you want to add property `year` as reactive data you need to set it some where (in mounted hook for example)

```
mounted() {
  this.$set(this.car, 'year', 2012)
},
```

[working example](https://jsbin.com/cebozaniyi/1/edit?html,js,output)

But to be honest when you know what properties you need then add them to your data at the start.

```
data() {
  return {
    car: {
      make: '',
      year: '',
    },
  },
},
```